# Conditional step based on currentBuild.result

Tags: jenkins

I'd like a step to only be performed when the currentBuild.result is not set to UNSTABLE, this is immediately after a test step has been performed, I've managed to figure out that if this is not the case it gets set to null in my pipeline. Comparing a variable to "" should work when trying to determine that it is null, however this does not appear to work in my job step:

```
stage('Post test') {
    when {
        expression {
            return (currentBuild.result == "")
        }
    }
    steps {
```

Can someone please advise as to what I should be using in my conditional step expression.

Answer (score 0):

Untested and not sure if this is exactly what you mean, but something like this?

```
stage('Post test') {
  steps {
    conditionalSteps {
      condition {
        status("Success","Success") # worst result, best result
      }
      steps {
        shell("echo 'this is my command'")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run this at the end of a build you can just wrap it in a post. If you want to run a command while continuing the pipeline, I think you would have to wrap it in a script closure. This is untested, but I believe it will work for what you want:

```
stages {
    stage('1') {}
    stage('2') {}
    stage('3') {
        steps {
            script {
                if (currentBuild.result == "UNSTABLE") {
                    println "this should be unstable"
                }
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        unstable {
            println "here be unstable"
        }
    }
}
```